# installer cannot determine applicationpath

Tags: tidesdk, installation

I am installing TideSDK for the first time.

I am working on Windows 7.

I downloaded the TideSDK-1.3.1-beta-win-x86 zip file.

I extracted the zip file to c:\ProgramData\TideSDK

When I attempt to run the installer application within c:\ProgramData\TideSDK\sdk\win32\1.3.1-beta\installer folder I get the following message:

"The installer cannot determine the application path"

What am I doing wrong?

Regard

Henry Hugo

Answer (score 1):

Follow all the the "Getting Started with TideSDK" steps:

http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started

The basic docs don't discuss the "installer" application.  Instead, the last part of Step 1 says to install Imagemagick and Wix 3.0... and then since you're just beginning I recommend you go to Step 2 where you get the TideSDK Developer App with the UI for creating and running a new app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use the developer application? This is a separate download form the SDK itself. If so download it from their website and install it, it's a .msi, easy to do.

http://www.tidesdk.org/